# Does the Suntrike / Tornado inscribed gems counter work?

Tags: dota-2

I've never seen anyone with those gems with something other than 0. Does those gems work and if yes, where do I need to put them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they work. I gifted a socketed hood to a friend some times ago and [the current counter is 242 Sunstrike kills and 16 Tornado kills](http://steamcommunity.com/id/benibou/inventory/?l=english#570_2_391959126). It was 0 when I gifted him. You can socket it on any Invoker items as long as there are socket in it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried, but there's [many many listings](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/570/Inscribed%20Hood%20of%20Endless%20Intellect?filter=sunstrike%20tornado) on the Marketplace with those gems having non-zero values, so they seem to work.